# Finding the value of variables from a given piecewise continuous function.

Tags: limits, piecewise-continuity, continuity

Given that $f(x)= \dfrac{\sin (a+1)x+ \sin x} {x}$  if $x<0.$

$$f(x)= c \text{ if } x=0.$$

$$f(x)= \frac{{\sqrt{x+bx^2}}-\sqrt {x}}{b \sqrt{x^3}} \text{ if } x>0.$$

Also given that the function is continuous at $x=0.$ Then find $a,b,c.$
I tried simplifying the left hand limit of the function and equated it to $f(0)$  and ended up with $a-c=-2$
Now i am having problem simplifying the right hand limit of the function.Please help. Also after finding the left hand limit and equation it to $f(0)$ how should i proceed to find the values required?

Comment: Is it $\sin((a+1)x)$ or $\sin(a+1) \cdot x$?

Answer (score 0):

To find limit of: 
$$f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{x+bx^2}-\sqrt{x}}{b\sqrt{x^3}}=\frac{\sqrt{1+bx}-1}{bx}$$
we set $p(x)=\sqrt{1+bx}-1$ and $q(x)=bx$. Thus $f(x)=\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$

Since $lim_{x\to 0} p(x)=lim_{x\to 0} q(x)=0 $ we can apply to L'Hospital's rule to get:
$$lim_{x\to 0} f(x)=lim_{x\to 0} \frac{p'(x)}{q'(x)}=lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\frac{b}{2}(1+bx)^{-\frac{1}{2}}}{b}=\frac{1}{2}$$

From this we can conclude that $c=\frac{1}{2}$

Now we can express $a$ as $a=c-2=-\frac{3}{2}$ while $b$ may take any real value.